# How to print a given value the certain number of times according to the values from the list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, cycle

Here is the code from W3SCHOOLS. Is there any way to have it done other way, maybe without 'while' cycle?

```
 def histogram( items ):
        for n in items:
            output = ''
            times = n
            while( times > 0 ):
              output += '*'
              times = times - 1
            print(output)
    
    histogram([2, 3, 6, 5])
```

Comment: You can multiply strings in python. To print `*` n times: `print('*' * n)`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, is it possible to multiply the string that way by each value that is in the list?

Comment: Sry, I thought it was clear from the accepted answer just to swap the `print` statements. I added an answer with the complete solution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it should have been clear, but I'm still too newbie to understand that stuff sometimes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
output = ''.join('*' for i in range(times))
```

finally code:

```
 def histogram( items ):
    for n in items:
        output = ''.join('*' for i in range(n))
        print(output)
    
histogram([2, 3, 6, 5])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
output = ''.join('*' for I in range(times))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply strings in python. To print `*` n times: `print('*' * n)`. I added the case `0` to the example to show that this works with `* 0`, too.

```
def histogram( items ):
    for n in items:
        print('*' * n)
    
histogram([2, 3, 0, 6, 5])
```

Out:

```
**
***

******
*****
```